# DataReader returning incorrect .net datatype for database table float column

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle.manageddataaccess

I have 1 Table in Oracle SQL Developer which containts 1 `column as Float`.`Data reader` have should return `Decimal for oracle float datatype` as per the table given here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-data-type-mappings

But the problem is datareader returns `double as datatype` for `Float Column` as shown below : [image]

But the problem is datareader returns double as datatype for `NREAL as Float` and `NFLOAT1 as float` and surprisingly
datareader returns `Decimal for both the column` as shown below :

[image]

Code :

```
static void Test()
        {
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection("connection string")
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "select id , NFLOAT from Numeric_Table";
                    using (OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            var columnName = reader.GetName(i);
                            var dotNetType = reader.GetFieldType(i);
                            var sqlType = reader.GetDataTypeName(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am using : **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client**

Is that a bug inside `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client library` or I am doing something wrong?

**Update :** Based on comments I want to mention something  :

Although I might have reference to different source documentation not applicable to oracle library I am using,bt still I am getting decimal datatype for my other 2 columns i.e NREAL and NFLOAT1 so why this behaviour is not consistent ?

Comment: `System.Data.OracleClient` <> `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` so it may have different binding

Comment: If you are using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`, then you are looking at the wrong documentation, because the one you linked is for  `System.Data.OracleClient`. Try https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/toc.htm

Comment: @Selvin But the thing is for other columns i.e NREAL and NFLOAT1 I am getting decimal datatype.What about that?

Comment: @Dirk But the thing is for other columns i.e NREAL and NFLOAT1 I am getting decimal datatype.What about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FLOAT` data type is not the whole picture here.  SQL Developer is not showing you that `NFLOAT` has a precision that's less than 50 while `NREAL` and `NFLOAT1` have precisions that are 50 or higher.  Left unspecified when created, the precision defaults 126, which is [the highest possible precision for the FLOAT data type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-10D4D073-866D-4BD4-B3E9-ED153D505A6A).

A simple test query will demonstrate the difference:

```
SELECT CAST(0 AS FLOAT(49)), CAST(0 AS FLOAT(50)) FROM DUAL
```

The first column will be returned as `System.Double`.  The second will be returned as `System.Decimal`.

In SQL Developer, right-click on the table and select "Edit..."  That dialog *does* show the defined precision for the column.

If you want `NFLOAT` to be returned as `System.Decimal` increase the precision to at least 50.

---

I've been combing the documentation and running my own tests lately.  It's a pet project and I don't use Oracle regularly so there's been a lot of trial and error. 
 The `DUMP` function has been quite helpful in determining if I have the right data type in an expression before seeing what ODP .NET does to it.

For another example of how ODP .NET returns different data types depending on the precision, consider `NUMBER(p,0)`.

```
Type     Min p    Max p
---------------------------
Int16    1        4
Int32    5        9
Int64    10       18
Decimal  19       38
```

I was hoping that `Byte` or `SByte` would be returned when `p` is 1 or 2 but that didn't pan out.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and for your valuable time and answer.As per the table shown here(https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14306/appendixa.htm) it seems like float could return anything which is so weird

Comment: No, that table isn't saying that those are the types that can be returned, but rather that those .NET types' ranges can be represented by the associated Oracle type, and vice-versa in the second table. ODP.NET will only return `Double` or `Decimal` for `FLOAT`. I tested `FLOAT` with precisions of 1, 49, 50, 126, and several others around those limits to confirm that. Any other type would require a cast or a conversion.

Comment: All right.Thank you so much.Your answer and comment are really helpful :)